# how to make PHP interpret URL GET parameters as array?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to interpret an array url param in PHP, but it's interpreted as string instead of an array.

On **client side**, the url is generated with js:
URL:

`let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0] //example https://www.test.com`

The get parameters are added with:

`const params = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array));`

`url += "?array="+params;`

for an example array of `[1010,1020,1030]`, the final url looks like:

`https://www.test.com?array=%5B%221010%22%2C%221020%22%2C%221030%22%5D`

On **server side** (PHP), I'm using `$_GET['array']` to get those data, the output looks like:

`string(22) "["1010","1020","1030"]"`

It is a syntactically correct array, but interpreted as string.
I know, I could use some string manipulations to get the array I want, but is there a way, that I can get an array right from scratch?

Comment: Just use [`json_decode`](//www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: I've tried json_decode, the result is the same.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and demonstrate your attempts.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, update: If i store the $_GET into a variable and json_decode the variable, it does not work, but if i json_decode the $_GET itself it works... now I feel stupid :) 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either decode the current parameters as JSON...

```php
$array = json_decode($_GET['array']);
```

or encode the array in a way PHP understands natively...

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
array.forEach((val) => {
  params.append("array[]", val); // note the "[]" suffix
});
url += `?${params}`;
```

```php
$array = $_GET['array'] ?? [];
```